# Nodemailer working in local environment but not I live website

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, deployment, nodemailer

I created a contact form that uses nodemailer to send emails from my web page. It works fine in a local environment but after uploading to the live website it gives me 404 not found when the POST request is called which to me suggests the code which is sending the email is not running. Is there something that needs to be changed in the code for it to work being made live?

Answer (score 0):

You can Disable Captcha temporarily, you can mail using new server,

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha